# How can the C++ program user be allowed to request to go back to one previous step of the program?

Tags: c++

I have just started doing a C++ project in which I try to create a very simple bank account system.

The question I have is how can I implement an option which would be displayed the whole time in order for the user to go back to some previous step (not only to the last one) for them to make any changes? I am not talking about input validation but rather about something the user can request if needs be.

Therefore, I would like to be able to allow the user to go back at any time to the first menu displayed in the program.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Implement menus as functions. To display a sub-menu, call a function which handles the sub-menu. To go back up to the main menu, return from the sub-menu function.

Comment: Finite State Machines.  FSMs are a way to swap back and forth between higher level states.  These are usually implemented with a switch() statement based on the state and have code to enter, run, and exit each state.

Comment: @Brian. I have removed the code, since it was not necessary to follow the question.